# Styling rating bar not working

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am trying to style my rating bar. I created style for rating bar and added it to my rating bar. But rating bar is ignoring it's style and picking it from AppTheme. 
Here is both styles

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#ffffff</item>
</style>
    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="AppTheme"/>
    <style name="foodRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/rating_stars</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item> <!-- your desired size -->
        <item name="android:maxHeight">48dip</item> <!-- your desired size -->
    </style>
```

rating_stars.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_selected" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_selected" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/stsr" />
</layer-list>
```

rating bar xml

```
<RatingBar
    android:theme="@style/foodRatingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:isIndicator="false" />
```

on applying this style it still picks color from AppTheme: colorCntrolNormal, colorAccent.
Is this way is wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: use android:theme="@style/yourTheme"

Comment: I am already using it

Comment: then try putting this inside your Rating bar theme <item name="colorAccent">@color/RatingAccentColor</item>

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<RatingBar
android:theme="@style/foodRatingBar"/>
```

to

```
<RatingBar
android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"/>
```

or

```
<RatingBar
style="@style/foodRatingBar"/>
```

Currently you are assigning an style to a theme attribute witch doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can change star color runtime using colorfilter(). try this

```
LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) rb_Ratings.getProgressDrawable();
stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_alpha_600),
                PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```